# Post Back into an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class TeamInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] teamInfo = new String[5][2];
        String[] teams = {"Team Penguin","Team Go Bokke","Team Pink","Team Orange","Team Os"};
        int[] scores = {232,315,0,185,388};
        for(int i = 0; i < teamInfo.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                teamInfo[i][0] = teams[i];
                teamInfo[i][1] = String.valueOf(scores[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Team ------ Score");
        for(int i = 0; i < teamInfo.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%s ------- %s\n",teamInfo[i][0],teamInfo[i][1]);
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I would like to get help, I have to add new scores for team 1 and 3 and post back into array.

Comment: It seems like you're almost there. You are already familiar with the idea that `teamInfo[i][1] = ...` sets the score for team `i`. By the way, your code could be a little easier to read and manage if you create a small inner `Team` class that holds both the name and the score, and use an array of those, rather than using parallel arrays (plus it's more convenient to pass around between methods, and to do operations like sort teams by score, etc.).

Comment: @Tiny He means update the array with a new score. It's unusual terminology but not unreasonable if you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second loop using `j` does nothing. Remove the loop and keep the body. Then, to change the score for team `x` do:

```
teamInfo[x][1] = String.valueOf(newScore);
```

Instead of working with index values, introduce constants like:

```
public static final int TEAM_NAME_INDEX = 0;
public static final int TEAM_SCORE_INDEX = 1;
```

and then write:

```
teamInfo[x][TEAM_SCORE_INDEX] = String.valueOf(newScore);
```

Comment: (Pedantic: You have a "first of all" without a "next..."!) 8-)

Comment: is it now better? :-)